# Keep the mouse cursor within the game window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make it so that the mouse cursor within the game window so that the cursor won't, for example, go into the other screen if you're using dual screens? I do not want to use the Screen.lockCursor since I want to be able to use the mousepointer inside the game and not make it hidden and centered which you do with the lockCursor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be able to help you `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;`

For more information look at the API at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-lockState.html